# Routing through a router which is in another network – “Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway.”

Tags: linux, debian, routing

We have the networks 192.168.88.0/22, 192.168.40.0/23, 192.168.10.0/24.
On 192.168.88.73 is a router (OS: Debian 10) to route from 192.168.40.0 to 192.168.10.0, it has an interface on 192.168.10.0, too.

On 192.168.40.131 is a client (also Debian 10) which should use the router on 192.168.88.73 to connect to 192.168.10.0. It can use the default gateway (192.168.40.251) to connect to 192.168.88.0/22 network. The client was in the past in the same network like the 192.168.88.73 router and it worked, so the router works (ping is ok).

I tried `ip route add 192.168.10.0/24 via 192.168.88.73 dev eth0` to create a static route to the router, but it doesn't work. The error message is: "Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway.".
The reason for this is obviously, the client is not in the same network like the router. But I don't find a solution.

I tried then `route add -host 192.168.88.73 gw 192.168.40.251` as Google suggests, although it is already default gateway. But it didn't work for me.

Comment: With the current setup you probably have to change routes on the 2 routers: "router" and "gateway".

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is quite obvious: your router needs a network interface inside the client network (192.168.40.0/23) and an interface inside the destination network (192.168.88.0/22) to be able to route packets...
After assigning the IP, you need to set this newly assigned IP as gateway:
`route add -net 192.168.88.0/22 gw 192.168.40.XXX`

And don't forget that the communication is bidirectional: unless you masquerade the routed ip, the destination network also needs a route into the client network!

and, of course, you need to do the same with the third network (192.168.10.0/24)

[Edit]

Obviously, there still is confusion... if you cannot add an network interface to the directly connected router, you need to put in place the routes on the gateway which has the interface. Let me draw a network layout for clarification.

```
Client A             Default Gateway            Router A          
192.168.40.131                                 192.168.88.73
   |                        |                         |
   |  ------------->.40.251 |                         |
   |                        |                         | --> Target Net
   |                        |                         |     (192.168.10.0/24)
   | <- 192.168.40.0/23 ->  |  <- 192.168.88.0/22 ->  |
```

I'll make the following assumptions:

- Your Default Gateway (192.168.40.251) also is part of the network 192.168.88.0/22, and has the ip 192.168.88.251 inside that network
- Your Router 192.168.88.73 also has a network interface in the 192.168.10.0/24 network

I do not know your network layout in detail, but these assumptions should clarify where to install what routes to achieve that the client A is able to reach the target network.

- Client A only needs one route: the default route over the Default gateway
- On your Default Gateway, you need to install the following route: `route add -net 192.168.10.0/24 gw 192.168.88.73`. This works because the default gateway has a network interface to the .88.0/22 network
- on your Router A, you need to install the "backwards" route: `route add -net 192.168.40.0/23 gw 192.168.88.251`

Hope this clarifies my answer.

Comment: As far as I understood after googling, there is a way to tell it "use router A to connect to router B" (in this case: default gateway of the /22 network = A, the destination router of the /23 network = B). But it didn't work for me. The reason of the problem was clear for me.

Comment: To add a network interface to the /23 network is not possible, there is no physical connection. This the problem. I'm looking for another solution.

The IP of the third network are masqueraded.

Comment: I enhanced my answer...